# What is the use of JavaFX Script?

Tags: javafx, javafx-1

I am new to this term *JavaFX Script*, just want to know more on the use of JavaFX Scripts.

thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX is a RIA framework, which is something similar to Silverlight and Flash. just check out the [JavaFx](http://javafx.com/samples/) and will get an idea about what exactly is,.

Answer (score 1):

Well, being as Oracle issued an 'end of life' statement pronouncing javafx 1.3 (and javafx script) dead come September 20, I would say that 'javafx script is of no use whatsoever, except perhaps for dealing with some legacy code'.

That's what I would say if I took your question literally and wanted to be a smart ass.  Java fx script was a UI language that went along with javafx 1.3, suns original javafx user interface multimedia oriented development kit.  It had its own scripting language interoperable with java.

This, many believed (mysself included) was a terrifically stupid move on suns part.  We wanted to code in java and didn't want to have to dick around with some stupid scripting language.  Oracle answered our prayers with JavaFX 2.0.  It is to put it simply, the user interface toolkit that replaces the old standard, Swing.  It's more than that -- it's based on it's own graphics engine Prism, so it pretty much replaces all of the old java multimedia classes, AWT, SWING, GRAPHICS 2D, etc. etc.  And you can write it in pure Java code.

It's also correct, as the user above pointed out, that it's a flash competitor.  Basically it's an SDK for producing rich cllient interfaces for the web or for the desktop... maybe even for mobile platforms but I'm not sure there.

Hope this helps -- if you want to learn more I suggest Apress publishings Pro JavaFX 2.0  Best book avbailable on Javafx 2.0  ( actually one of only two in print to date, but still damn well written)

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be a Flash compete.